# Searching for surrounding suburbs based on latitude & longitude using Objective C

Tags: iphone, core-data, latitude-longitude

I need to identify items of interest nearby to a particular latitude/longitude. I have two sets of objects stored in Core Data:

```
PostalArea
- latitude
- longitude
- postcode

Store
- name 
- latitude
- longitude
```

I need to be able to retrieve a record from the `PostalArea` table, and then find stores which are closeby.

Most of the examples I've found are SQL based. I'm hoping someone can assist me with getting this working with Core Data. Ideally I would like to limit the result set to a certain number (say, 10), as opposed to limiting it based on distance.

EDIT: pulling all the records into memory is an option, if need be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most common solution to this is to determine a min/max of both lat and long and then do a predicate based on those.  That would narrow your search to within a circle and then with those remaining objects in memory you can sort by closest to the point.

### Update

Once you have the objects in memory you can then do some fun things with them.  For instance you could have a transient value called 'currentPoint' and you could then KVO on the resulting array such as:

```
[resultingArray setValue:aPoint forKey:@"currentPoint"];
```

Then you could have a method that returns the distance from that point which you can sort by.

That is one example, I am sure there are other ways but the general idea is to get a subset of locations into memory so that you can then calculate distance and finally sort.

Comment: Fair enough, but how would I go about sorting by closing to the point? I think that's actually the answer I am seeking :)

Comment: Sorry, guess I'm not being that clear - I need to create the method for calculating the distance.

Comment: That was not your original question. Creating the method to determine the distance between two coordinates is already [answered several times on SO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27928/how-do-i-calculate-distance-between-two-latitude-longitude-points).

Comment: I think it was - I said I need to be able to retrieve a record from the table, and find stores nearby. I was hoping to be able to do that without pulling all the records into memory, but will if I have to.

Comment: You do not need to pull all of the records into memory.  You can pull in a subset into memory based on a distance.  Calculate a min/max lat/long and filter on that.  It will then give you everything within that range (i.e. everything within 10 miles of the point).

Comment: Ok, fair enough. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

How would you feel about a REST service option?  Is you use the Google APIs, you can query for exactly those things.  There are plenty of JSON interfaces available for Objective C.

Comment: Thanks, but REST is not an option. This needs to work offline.